# Block IPs on Google Ads API v2 Beta using Python Library

Tags: google-ads-api, ads-api

I'm trying to block an IP list through Google API v2 but I'm getting the error "Criteria type can not be targeted." on field: operations, on field: create, on field: ip_block. 
Another doubt that I have, is if I will need to repeat the create operation for each IP on my list or there is a way to put multiple Ip on the same request.

```
client = (google.ads.google_ads.client.GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage(path="./google-ads.yaml"))
campaign_criterion_operation = client.get_type('CampaignCriterionOperation', version='v2')
campaign_criterion = campaign_criterion_operation.create
campaign_criterion.campaign.value = campaign_service.campaign_path(customer, campaign)
campaign_criterion.ip_block.ip_address.value = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
campaign_criterion_response = campaign_criterion_service.mutate_campaign_criteria(customer, [campaign_criterion_operation])

for reponse in campaign_criterion_response.results:
    print('Added campaign criterion "%s".' % reponse.resource_name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you are getting the error because you haven't set the criterion to negative. Im not using the python library but i am using the PHP one.

This is what mine looks like;

```
$campaign_criterion = new CampaignCriterion([
    'ip_block' => new IpBlockInfo([
        'ip_address' => 'IP_ADDRESS_HERE'
    ]),
    'negative' => true, // setting it to negative
    'campaign' => ResourceNames::forCampaign('XXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX')
]);
```

And yes, you have to create a campaign criterion per IP Address you want to block.

Comment: Hi James, its it. I added campaign_criterion.negative.value = True and worked like a charm.